# I need help writing an if then statement using 2 criterion of ltv and credit score

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Please help! I've been ripping my hair out trying to figure this out on Excel.

I'm trying to write a code that outputs a percentage value based off of LTV and Credit score range. If the LTV is equal to or above 75, and has a credit score >725 then -.25. If the LTV is equal to or above 75 with a credit score between 724 and 675 then +1.25. If the LTV is equal to or above 75 with a credit score 625-674 then +1.75

I also need to write a statement if the LTV is below 75 for the same credit socres above. 725, 724-675, 674-625.

I keep getting an error that Im using too many arguments.

Comment: show what you did first

Answer (score 0):

A2 is LTV and B2 is Credit score

```
=CHOOSE((A2<75)*4+(B2>=625)+(B2>=675)+(B2>=725)+1,"error",1.75,1.25,-0.25,"error","<75 & 625-674","<75 & 675-724","<75 & >725")
```

[image]